# Question downvoted with no comments as to why

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I value this community and try to provide value to it.

Recently, I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363824/get-wifi-ssid-and-name-upon-connection) which was originally +1 but then moved to be -2 in the space of about an hour.

In which ways is it a poor question?  What could I do to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes up from time to time.

- The best advice I can give you is to look at how other questions are structured on the site that are popular and possibly related to the area you're asking your question in. Then model your question off of their structure.
- Additionally always provide as much detail about OS, versions etc. within your question and try to tell a story. This last bit is to explain what you've done to this point in how you've attempted to solve the question yourself.
- Also don't be afraid to reframe your question as new details come to light. Don't use comments for this. Edit your question and incorporate details into your question as you refine and focus it to an eventual solution.

Also remember that voting up/down are signals to you. Try not to interpret these as a personal attack of any sort. Some will leave comments but many do not. It's just part of the SE model and something you have to come to terms with.

Comment: About turning it into a story: Don't go overboard with this. I personally find it a bit tedious having to read several paragraphs of unrelated details. Short and concise is better, but obviously with reasoning, expectations, results etc. included.

Comment: @Kusalananda - agreed, don't give them every twist/turn about how you've been working the issue. My main point with saying "tell a story" is to provide meaningful contexts around your issue.